# How many active streams can one node.js process handle

Tags: node.js, process, stream

I need to monitor a bunch of twitter streams (using twitter's streaming API) in node.js.  Which approach would be "better"?

- Run multiple processes, 1 Process per Stream
- Run 1 process that handles all of the streams

At this point I do not know how many streams I will have, but ideally the set up should be able to scale to 10000+ open streams.

Edit for more context:
Most or all processing will be done by another server.  Just looking to manage the streams in a reliable, maintainable and performant way.

Comment: Which nodejs module are you using to connect to the Twitter streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question depends a lot on

1. How often the tweeters are tweeting
2. What you are doing in processing the tweets

In particular, if the tweets are only coming in sporadically, like 1 tweet per user every 3+ minutes, then I think 1 instance of node should be fine for handling all of them.

Comment: Thanks!. The streams process will be doing little to no processing beyond putting the data in Redis.  Another process will handle the parsing and long term data storage.

So I guess what you are saying is that the quantity of IO is more important than the overhead maintaining streams/processes?

Comment: @zackz: Definitely. If there is little processing, Node should be able to handle thousands of such streams. You will probably need to adjust the number of open files per user, though, for Redis and Node. To scale, you can run one Node.js process per core using the [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

- Run single process, measure cpu load. If one cpu is not enough, then run as much processes as CPU cores, try to distribute streams evenly between processes.